# Parsing JSON in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a postgres database that stores student data that includes their names, password and group they in. Its stored as a JSON and I am trying to extract data for each of these categories namely,

group, username, password and group

[image: JSON data with square brackets on the sides]

Since there is a square bracket on the sides of the JSON, I am unable to extract the required data. Kindly help..

Comment: That's a JSON array

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

```
postgres=# select * from t_jsonb;
 a |                                                  b                                                  
---+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | [{"group": "math", "groupid": "g1", "password": "pass12345", "username": "mark", "prefixtype": ""}]
 2 | [{"group": "stat", "groupid": "g3", "password": "help1111", "username": "scott", "prefixtype": ""}]
 3 | [{"group": "math", "groupid": "g1", "password": "1234555", "username": "martha", "prefixtype": ""}]
(3 rows)
```

## AS TABLE

```
postgres=#select e.groupid, e.username,e.password,e.group
from public.t_jsonb, jsonb_to_recordset(b) as e( groupid varchar, username varchar,password varchar, "group" varchar );

 groupid | username | password  | group 
---------+----------+-----------+-------
 g1      | mark     | pass12345 | math
 g3      | scott    | help1111  | stat
 g1      | martha   | 1234555   | math
(3 rows)
```

## AS STRING

```
postgres=#select (e.groupid, e.username,e.password,e.group)
from public.t_jsonb, jsonb_to_recordset(b) as e( groupid varchar, username varchar,password varchar, "group" varchar );

          row        
--------------------------
 (g1,mark,pass12345,math)
 (g3,scott,help1111,stat)
 (g1,martha,1234555,math)
(3 rows)
```

Hope this answer will help you in your future development.